# In Wordpress: Group same-day posts on the index page

Tags: wordpress, themes, date, posts

i'm looking for a way to code the loop in such a way that it places posts that are in the same day within a div. Im doing this so I can put a separator between the different days to show users that they are looking at another day. An example of this in action is in [informedlondon.com](http://informedlondon.com), where once a days worth of posts ends, there is a little graphic in between to separate the posts. This is what Google's Blogger platform does by default, thats why it was easy for the divider to be put between the different days of posts.

I'm guessing there must be a tutorial about it somewhere but I have checked and can't seem to find one. I have a sneaky suspicion that it's very easy and i'm just being a dunce. Would appreciate some help.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method to accomplish things like this is to 'hold' the current date in a variable. Before your loop: `var $current_date` and then inside your loop, a simple if statement:

```
if( $current_date != get_the_date('d-m-Y') ){
    echo '<h2>Posts for '.get_the_date('d-m-Y').'</h2>';
    $current_date = get_the_date('d-m-Y');
}
```

So in effect, you're checking with each post whether the date of the post is different than the date of the last post rendered (in the 'holding' variable, `$current_date`). If it is, you print a title with the new date, and set the 'holding' variable to the new date. If not, nothing happens and the post is printed as usual.

Comment: I think "the_date" statement will cause an error. Try get_the_date().

Comment: You're absolutely right, corrected (line 2) - thanks for that catch!

Comment: They say you know a true genius by the simplicity of his/her answer. You my friend are a genius